# How to SELECT and Count range of rows in a Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `projects` which has a column called `projects-bug`(stored values from 0 to 2000).There are about 2000 rows stored in the table and I need to get COUNT of projects in like 4 ranges as:

0 - 500 
  501 - 1000 
1001 - 1500 
1501 - 2000

in a way that show how many projects are in each of ranges?
Can you please let me know if this is possible in single line SQL? and how to do this?

Comment: `0 - 500 ` is stored in your record as varchar?

Comment: no they are all numbers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(`project-bug` between 0 and 500) as 0_500,
       sum(`project-bug` between 501 and 1000) as 501_1000,
       sum(`project-bug` between 1001 and 1500) as 1001_1500,
       sum(`project-bug` between 1501 and 2000) as 1501_2000
from projects
```

Comment: Yes, you sum up how many times the condition inside the `sum()` is true. That is conditional counting

Answer (score 1):

What if you try like below using `SUM()` function

```
select SUM(case when `projects-bug` between 0 and 500 then 1 else 0 end) as sum1,
SUM(case when `projects-bug` between 501 and 1000 then 1 else 0 end) as sum2,
SUM(case when `projects-bug` between 1001 and 1500 then 1 else 0 end) as sum3,
SUM(case when `projects-bug` between 1501 and 2000 then 1 else 0 end) as sum4
from projects
```

Comment: Hi Rahul can you please let me know why are using the `then 1 else 0 end` in the script?

Comment: @Suffii, that's conditional  and I am using CASE statement here, so it's the syntax. if the condition matches then only it will take value 1. You can also use `sum(<condition>)` same what Jurgen have shown in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return separate rows for each count, you could do something like this:

```
  SELECT CONCAT(q.lo,' - ',q.hi)  AS range_
       , COUNT(p.`projects-bug`)  AS count_
    FROM ( SELECT 0 AS lo, 500 AS hi
           UNION ALL SELECT 501, 1000 
           UNION ALL SELECT 1001, 1500
           UNION ALL SELECT 1501, 2000
         ) q
    JOIN projects p
      ON p.`projects-bug` BETWEEN q.lo AND q.hi  
   GROUP BY q.lo, q.hi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [blahblah] as calculatedRangeNum
     , CONCAT(MIN(id), '-', MAX(id)) AS idSpan  -- not necessary of course, merely for confirmation
     , COUNT(1) AS rowsInSpan
FROM someTable
GROUP BY calculatedRangeNum
;
```

where [blahblah] for your example could be

```
(id-1) DIV 500
```

or (more precisely)

```
IF(id BETWEEN 0 AND 500, 1
  , IF(id BETWEEN 501 AND 1000, 2
  , [etc....]))
```

Edit: You could even add in a `WHERE` clause so you could do something like only getting the number of active/expired/whatever projects.